# Modifying the scope of an Isolated Scope Directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand Isolated Scopes in directives. I have the following html:

```
<div new-test>
  <h4>new scope : {{msg}}</h4>
  <button ng-click="clicker()">new test</button>
  <hr>
</div>
<div same-test>
  <h4>same as parent scope : {{msg}}</h4>
  <button ng-click="clicker()">same test</button>
  <hr>
</div>
<div isolate-test>
  <h4>isolated scope : {{msg}}</h4>
  <button ng-click="clicker()">isolated test</button>
  <button ng-click="ftn()">own ftn</button>
  <hr>
</div>
```

And the following angular directives:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')

.directive('newTest', [function() {
    return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.msg = 'new scope';
        scope.clicker = function() {
          console.log("New Scope");
        };
    }
  }
}])

.directive('sameTest', [function() {
    return {
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.msg = 'same scope';
        scope.clicker = function() {
          console.log("Same Scope");
        };
    }
  }
}])

.directive('isolateTest', [function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.msg = 'isolated scope'; // this doesn't exist
        scope.clicker = function() {
          console.log("Isolated Scope"); // this is never called
        };
        scope.ftn = function() {
          console.log("own ftn"); // or this
        };
    }
  }
}]);
```

None of the functions or variables that I thought I added to the scope of the `isolateTest` directive exist. If I click the `isolate test` button, the `clicker` function in the `same-test` directive is getting called instead. How come? I thought that button exists in an isolated scope along with any other elements between the div elements? How can I add a 'local' function to the scope of an isolated directive like `isolateTest`? Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kergoog/rjcmjd0k/2/).

Can someone please explain what is happening here. Thanks!

Comment: As name implies isolated scope is visible only within directive code and template. You don't use template with your directives, instead you bind on nested HTML elements that inherit parent scope (or child scope in case when `scope: true` is used). Isolated scope was designed to be used with reusable components, and tries to provide much security between directives and controllers - e.g. avoids name clashes on scopes. What you want in 3th case is a custom directive template [example here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html#a-basic-directive).

Comment: Thanks. So within the `isolation-test` div the scope is actually the parent scope (same as `same-test`). While the isolate scope is inaccessible because no template is defined. Thanks, I didn't understand the relationship between templates and isolated scope before. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `isolateTest` directive, I switched your `scope: {}` to `scope: true`, and I'm able to get your functions to fire.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rjcmjd0k/11/

```
.directive('isolateTest', [function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.msg = 'isolated scope';
        scope.clicker = function() {
       console.log("Isolated Scope");
      };
      scope.ftn = function() {
        console.log("own ftn");
      };
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew that changing the scope to `true` does that. csharpfolk's comment clarified how isolated scope is really working here.